# Как получить value option у select

Tags: html

Как передать id option а не имя? Например:

```
<select id="server" name="server" class="placeholder">
    <option id="0">Выберите сервер</option>
    <option id="1">Test</option>    
</select>
```

Как получать не отображаемый текст а `<option id="1">`, в этом случае 1.

Comment: чем не нравится стандартный `value`?

Comment: @Gedweb с чего ты взял, что вопрос не имеет отношения к PHP?

Comment: @Gedweb вопрос имеет прямое отношение к PHP.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо!

Comment: где получить? на стороне сервера или клиента?

Answer (score 1):

```js
server.addEventListener('change', function() {
  listener(server);
});

function listener(elem) {
  var id = elem.querySelector(':checked').getAttribute('id');

  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<select id="server" name="server" class="placeholder">
  <option id="0">Выберите сервер</option>
  <option id="1">Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: к чему эти костыли из js?